# how can I parse http post content included well formed XML and binary data?

Tags: xml, soap, mms, mm7

I am receiving mobile originated MMS to some web app as http post. When I receive the content it includes some raw information, a well formed XML and Binary formatted data (i.e. Image).

I want to fetch the XML so I can parse it and binary data from the content to convert it into an image.

Following is the content sample:

```
    ------=_Part_121809_1523072928.1286496211187
    Content-Type: text/xml
    Content-ID: <soap-start>

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ns1:Envelope xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns3="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-6-MM7-1-4"><ns1:Header><ns3:TransactionID ns1:mustUnderstand="1">GW0110L-M1007N6-M200331G0-SNSRPN</ns3:TransactionID></ns1:Header><ns1:Body><ns3:DeliverReq><ns3:MM7Version>6.8.0</ns3:MM7Version><ns3:LinkedID>GW0110L-M1007N6-M200331G0-SNSRPN</ns3:LinkedID><ns3:Sender><ns3:Number>+16123060744/TYPE=PLMN</ns3:Number></ns3:Sender><ns3:Recipients><ns3:To><ns3:Number displayOnly="false">466466</ns3:Number></ns3:To></ns3:Recipients><ns3:TimeStamp>2010-10-08T00:03:29.897Z</ns3:TimeStamp><ns3:Priority>Normal</ns3:Priority><ns3:Subject>New Message</ns3:Subject><ns3:UACapabilities UAProf="MF:304~Model:SPHM320ZSS"/><ns3:Content allowAdaptations="true" href="cid:default.cid"/></ns3:DeliverReq></ns1:Body></ns1:Envelope>
    ------=_Part_121809_1523072928.1286496211187
    Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
        boundary="----=_Part_121810_281628656.1286496211187"
    Content-ID: <default.cid>

    ------=_Part_121810_281628656.1286496211187
    Content-Type: application/smil
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
    Content-ID: <<applicationsmil_1.smil>>

    <smil>
      <head>
        <layout>
          <root-layout height="160" width="160"/>
          <region height="120" id="Image" left="0" top="0" width="160"/>
          <region height="40" id="Text" left="0" top="120" width="160"/>
        </layout>
      </head>
      <body>
        <par dur="5s">
          <img region="Image" src="imagejpeg_2.jpg"/>
        </par>
      </body>
    </smil>
    ------=_Part_121810_281628656.1286496211187
    Content-Type: image/jpeg
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
    Content-ID: <<imagejpeg_2.jpg>>

    ÿØÿà�JFIF������ÿÛ�C�
$4á%ñ&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚâãäåæçèéêòóôõö÷øùúÿÚ���?�ýø¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(�¢Š(YÕmt?êšÞ H³Óí$ºœ¢å¶D¥›‚×à/Æß|Ô¾6èZ^kÚ<º¬ú„ÏwföþG÷Q7§È¿süîl¯è
ä¢Ù²Kl÷qÈ|·T?
÷·nþþ>5k:ý¶<M¦7†µ_ÚørÊ{k;û
òÁ½÷¶ç‹z?ÈŸ'Ï÷6r¾gˆ ±‘£7­›],—^ŸvæÊîŒ¹o~ÿ�Ò<¾Ú?�ëšÏµ»)tÛ
="‚Ù,¦Kt“æÛ±þ÷ëÄ.´[ï‚·3ÛßÜ[Yß\¬%¹ß.ç•+Ôl5ÏÚþÌþ0×¯-m~Ó¨^3[E,?Åüü_ü¹[ßø"ßAðm„Ž›s~×>dßdº»~_üzº£R¤å÷SÙëoÅ˜Tååå“³í`Ô¬e‡ÅÞÒî5›¯ô]ÛÝ?t»v|¿í|ÔË?R_ø“V‹Ä>
```

Answer (score 0):

The information about which platform/framework you're going to use for your purpose
is missing in your question.

If you're using Java, try this lib:
http://jmmslib.sourceforge.net/